# Adding Wordpress Updated Post Date PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

My theme developer won't help give me an answer on how to add this feature to the current theme. I looked into the Wordpress documentation and tried to add code to function.php file but it placed the code on the top of the page. I tried to add the PHP code Wordpress suggests but it broke the theme.

Looks like this is a custom code seeing as it is a custom theme.

Any help would be most welcome.

**Currently:**
*July 11, 2017 in CATEGORY 0 comments*

**Looking to have:**
*July 11, 2017 in CATEGORY 0 comments*
*Updated: July 23, 2017 at 7:00am*

```
            <!-- ARTICLE DATE : begin -->
                `<div class="article-date">
                    <i class="ico tp tp-clock2"></i>
                    <span class="article-date-holder">
                    <?php if ( lsvr_get_field( 'article_detail_categories_enable', true, true ) ) : ?>
                        <?php $categories_html = ''; ?>
                        <?php $terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_id(), 'category' ); ?>
                        <?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) : ?>
                            <?php $categories_html .= '<a href="' . get_term_link( $term ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>, '; ?>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        <?php if ( $categories_html !== '' ) : ?>
                            <?php $categories_html = rtrim( $categories_html, ', ' ); ?>
                            <?php echo sprintf( '%s in %s', get_the_date(), $categories_html ); ?>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <?php echo get_the_date(); ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?php echo get_the_date(); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    </span>
                    <?php if ( lsvr_get_field( 'article_detail_author_enable', false, true ) ) : ?>
                    <span class="article-author">
                        <?php echo sprintf( 'by %s', get_the_author_posts_link() ); ?>
                    </span>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if( comments_open() ) : ?>
                    <span class="article-comments">
                        <?php $comment_count = get_comment_count( get_the_ID() ); ?>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>#comments"><?php echo @sprintf( __( '%d comments', 'lsvrtheme' ), $comment_count['approved'] ); ?></a>
                    </span>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>`
                <!-- ARTICLE DATE : end -->
```

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for might be [the_modified_time().](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_modified_time)

Don't put the code in functions.php, instead, echo the_modified_time() (and any parameters) in the template file where you need the modified time text to display (use within the loop to get info about the current post).

Comment: It's on a special section called article.php